# @Repository is not autowired

Tags: java, spring, jpa, repository, spring-data-jpa

I have a projected checked into GitHub here
https://github.com/romeoopk/demo
Please note that this is not a "complete" working project but in progress!

I have two data sources (h2 mem DB and Cassandra)
The aim of the project is to hide the implementation behind the Service.

there are two profiles I am looking against

dev - goes against h2

test - goes against Cassandra

when I run against test, it runs fine as expected but when I run against dev, I get the following message

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.demo.service.H2HotelServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.example.demo.repository.HotelRepository' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.demo.repository.HotelRepository' in your configuration.

I am unsure, how to have a proper injection so that the H2HotelRepository and H2HotelByLetterRepository get used for querying towards H2

any help is highly appreciated!!!

Comment: You should decide, if you want to use Spring data repositories or your own implementation. Right now you have mingled that together in a very confusive way. I suggest to have a look at a Spring Data tutorial, how to use the repository interfaces correctly.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the comments. As i mentioned the project is not a complete one so it was work under progress :) nonetheless, I would go with a custom implementation going away from spring data jpa!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your repository classes under cassandra folder is like this

```
@Repository
@Profile("test")
public class CassandraHotelRepository implements HotelRepository<Hotel> {
....
}

@Repository
@Profile("test")
public class CassandraHotelByLetterRepository implements HotelByLetterRepository<HotelByLetter, HotelByLetterKey> {
 ....
}
```

But in your h2 folder you have declared as

```
@Repository
@Profile("dev")
public abstract class H2HotelRepository implements CrudRepository<Hotel, String>, HotelRepository<Hotel> {
  ...
}
@Repository
@Profile("dev")
public abstract class H2HotelByLetterRepository implements CrudRepository<HotelByLetter, HotelByLetterKey>, HotelByLetterRepository<HotelByLetter, HotelByLetterKey> {
 .....
}
```

As you can clearly see in h2 folder i.e. for profile dev, there is no concrete class. Both of your repositories under h2 are `abstract`.

Remove abstract and it should work fine.

Comment: Hi. Thanks it worked! I just removed the abstract keyword  and it did the trick

Comment: I clicked the green tick. I think that means accept :)